# JavaEE default error handler servlet does not catch thrown errors

Tags: google-app-engine, exception, jakarta-ee, error-handling, jersey

My problem is that the error handler code I register does not work on all errors. In my web.xml I registered my default error handler:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ShowErrorHandlerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>tools.ErrorHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ShowErrorHandlerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/showerror</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/showerror</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/showerror</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <location>/showerror</location>
    </error-page>
```

I am using Jersey to map rest request, so e.g. something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/throwError")
public void testThrowUnauthException() {
    // String s = null;
    // s.toString();
    // /*
    // * this nullpointer exception would be caught correctly because of
    // * <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type> in the web.xml
    // */
    throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

The WebApplicationException is not caught and the default jetty 401 error page is shown:

> HTTP ERROR 401
>
> Problem accessing /v1/locations/throwError. Reason:
>
> ```
> UNAUTHORIZED 
> Powered by Jetty
> ```

Registering

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/showerror</location>
</error-page>
```

does not work, but it works for 404 errors..

Does someone have an idea why this is happening? I need to catch all errors with the ErrorHandlerServlet to convert them to json error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jersey is overriding Jetty behaviour, so it is not taking the value on the XML. One way to solve it (maybe not the most elegant):

```
@Context HttpServletResponse res;
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String doFoo(){
    try {
        //Code that causes the error
    } catch (Exception e) {
        res.sendRedirect("/showError");
    }
    return "";
}
```

Another idea would be extending WebApplicationException and manage the responses yourself (probably the best)

Comment: ok thanks :) and how do i override the behaviour for a specific exception?

Comment: Extend WebApplicationException, there is a constructor that takes an int, being it the error code. Override this method and do a switch inside this method, with all the redirects for the codes you want, then a default for the others calling the super constructor with the int code (to let the super class handle the other codes) Hope it helps :)